# Remove object required message in cancel option of inputbox

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to remove error message(object required message) that pops out from the input box whenever the user presses the **cancel** button?

```
Sub WorkingDuoFunctionCode()

    Dim rng As Range, inp As Range

    'to remove 0 values that may be a result of a formula or direct entry.

    Set inp = Selection
    inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
    rng.Parent.Activate
    rng.Select
    inp.Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True

    For Each cell In Range("A1:CL9935")
       If cell.Value = "0" Then cell.Clear
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem? Sorry for not understand. I think, you should say more or should post code what you got error.

Comment: Application,input box usually gives an error message whenever the user trys to cancel. so im asking how can that error message be eliminated. its generated by the vba system . here is an example

Sub WorkingDuoFunctionCode()
    Dim rng As Range, inp As Range

        Set inp = Selection
        inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
        Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
        rng.Parent.Activate
        rng.Select
        inp.Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True
        
   For Each cell In Range("A1:CL9935")
 If cell.Value = "0" Then cell.Clear
 Next
 
 
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure why you are using the inputbox, you don't even use it in the code.

This should take care of the errors.

```
Sub WorkingDuoFunctionCode()

    Dim rng As Range, inp As Range

    'to remove 0 values that may be a result of a formula or direct entry.
    Set rng = Nothing
    Set inp = Selection
    inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Copy to", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Cancelled...", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        rng.Parent.Activate
        rng.Select
        inp.Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True
    End If
    For Each cell In Range("A1:CL9935")
        If cell.Value = "0" Then cell.Clear
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: this works perfectly with no errors thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

That is not a **InputBox** error. That is your wrong usage. In your code, you immediately set value from **InputBox** return. That may cause error because of setting empty value("") to an **Range** object.

So, you need to modify as follow:

```
Sub WorkingDuoFunctionCode()

    Dim rng As Range, inp As Range
    Dim inputRange As String

    'to remove 0 values that may be a result of a formula or direct entry.

    Set inp = Selection

    inp.Interior.ColorIndex = 37

    inputRange = Application.InputBox("Copy to")

    If Not IsEmpty(inputRange) Then

        Set rng = Range(inputRange)

        rng.Parent.Activate
        rng.Select
        inp.Copy
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Link:=True

        For Each cell In Range("A1:CL9935")
           If cell.Value = "0" Then 
               cell.Clear
           End If
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Not tested. Suggestion for you. If it is not work, let me know.